# How to slowly echo out results

Tags: php, echo

Not sure if this is going to be possible with PHP but i id it by accident before and i forget how i did it, basically i had made a script that echo'd out a result but i added a u sleep between the three results and it made it so every like 1 second a result would be echo, i need to create a script to echo out a response every 3 seconds. Any tips? Sorry, I'm new to it. When i try the below code it doesn't work.

```
<?php
echo "test";
sleep(2);
echo "test2";
sleep(2);
echo "test2";
echo $answer;
?>
```

Comment: You can `flush()`, or use JavaScript to slowly append content.

Comment: this should be done clientside, not server side

Comment: this shouldn't be done on the server side since the operation isn't time consuming and just output your results slowly client side

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Just makes the page execution time sleep. (Doesnt load the page for  x time, x being the time of sleep you did.) @ScottLawson

Comment: Flush seems to do the job, though.. I will probably do it client side. I just needed a refreshment on how to do it.

Answer (score -1):

The output will be buffered until the script ends or you flush() it manually.

```
<?php
echo "test";
sleep(2);
flush();
echo "test2";
sleep(2);
flush();
echo "next";
```

When run in cli, this is the best option.
When run in browser, check if you're not better off using browser-based technologies like javascript to slowly display parts of the output.